# Como hago para guardar un titulo y un párrafo en mysql desde php y html

Tags: php, html, mysql

alguien sabe como puedo insertar un título y un  párrafo que estan en un html, a mysql desde php, ya que al hacer la inserción de estos no me los guarda en la tabla. No se si debe de utilizar alguna etiqueta en articular, por que si utilizo un input(Text), no me serviria.

Código HTML

```
<div id="contenido">
        <form  method="POST" action="guardararticulo.php" ></form>
        <h2 name="titulo">Articulos para Mostrar</h2>
        <p name="descripcion">Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página
            Contenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la página
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="guardar">
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php 

include("Conexion.php");

$objConexion = Conectarse ();

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descri = $_POST['descripcion'];

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    header("location:login.html");
}

$iduser=$_SESSION ['id_usuario'];

$insertarart = "INSERT INTO tbl_articulos (Id_Usuario_FK ,Titulo_Art,Descripcion) 
VALUES ('$iduser','$titulo','$descri')";
$resultadoinsert = $objConexion->query($insertarart) or die($objConexion->error);

if($resultadoinsert > 0){

    echo "<script>
    alert('Registro Exitoso');
    window.location = 'iniciologin.html';
    </script>";
}
else{
    echo "<script>
    alert('Error al Registrase');
    window.location = 'iniciologin.html';
    </script>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Tus elementos están fuera de `<form ...> </form>` por eso no están llegando al `$_POST`, debes ponerlos dentro y puedes usar `input` y/o `textarea` (para contenido amplio) **pero dentro del `form`** y esto `<input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="guardar">` también debe estar dentro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio mucho

Answer (score 0):

Estás cerrando la etiqueta *form* en la misma línea en la que lo estás abriendo. De nada te sirve si lo cerrás ahí. Esta tiene que cerrarse luego del '*submit*'.

Si no entendí mal, lo que estás queriendo sería algo así:

```
<div id="contenido">
    <form  method="POST" action="guardararticulo.php" >
        <input type="text" name="titulo" value="Articulos para Mostrar">
        <textarea name="descripcion">
            Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página
            Contenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la página
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="guardar">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cesar, efectivamente tenia mal la etiqueta del form, saludos.